# Display CiviCRM Price Set end date in view

Tags: drupal-views, price-sets

I am trying to display the end date of a price set in a view.  It seems like that data is stored in Price Field, but I can't figure out how to make that accessible in the view.  I installed the CiviCRM Entities module, which has given me access to the Price Set entity, but not the Price Field entity.

I am using Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 4.6.28.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the CiviCRM Entity Views Extras module you will be able to add a Views relationship to access the price field fields in your view

Comment: Any chance this "add a Views relationship to access the price field fields in your view" part is somehow documented, so we won't poke around guessing?

Comment: Documentation? What's that? :) Anyway I chill in the Drupal or civicrm entity channels of chat.civicrm.org if you want some help, ping @jackrabbithanna